# Chained promises in Promise.all without wrapper Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

Is it possible for Promise.all to return the last value of the chain without a wrapper promise?

**Without using await, it doesn't work in my context**

Without wrapper example :

```
function sum1(x){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(t => resolve(x+1),3000)
  })
}
const p1 = sum1(1);

p1
.then(sum1)
.then(sum1)

Promise.all([p1])
.then(v => console.log(v[0]));
```

It logs 2 instead of the expected 4.

But if I use a wrapper it works :

```
function sum1(x){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(t => resolve(x+1),3000)
  })
}

function sum3(x){
  return sum1(x)
  .then(sum1)
  .then(sum1)
}
const p2 = sum3(1);

Promise.all([p2])
.then(v => console.log(v[0]));
```

But in my context it gets complicated if I need to create and name a wrapper function for every chain of promises...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the value returned by `p1.then(sum1).then(sum1)` and call `Promise.all` on this value. It waits for the resolution of the promise chain not only the first one. Here is an example:

```
function sum1(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(t => resolve(x + 1), 10);
  });
}

const p1 = sum1(1);
const p2 = p1.then(sum1).then(sum1);

Promise.all([p1]).then(v => console.log('P1', v[0]));
Promise.all([p2]).then(v => console.log('P2', v[0]));
```

Comment: it looks not as good as the original chaining promises from my perspective :D

Comment: Sure but I thought he wanted to to have a separation between the two, that's why. Otherwise I agree with the original promise it's even clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: the problem with your code was that you store in `const p1 = sum1(1);` only first part of chain, and in `Promise.all([p1])` you get result only from this first part (one solution is just to store all chain in p1 like this: `p1=sum1(1).then(sum1).then(sum1)`. However in your case, you don't need to use Promie.all at all (because in your example there is only one promise p1/2 ):

```js
function sum1(x){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(t => resolve(x+1),300)
  })
}

// Promise.all([sum1(1).then(sum1).then(sum1)]).then(r => console.log(r)); // this works too

sum1(1).then(sum1).then(sum1).then(r => console.log(r));
```

Comment: Forgot to mention no await

Comment: @Mojimi why not await ?

Comment: Well in my context we're forced to use dojo widgets and it wraps everything in a function I can't access so await doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Actually all I had to do was call the chain in the variable declaration, so it references the last called promise

```
function sum1(x){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(t => resolve(x+1),3000)
  })
}

//The change is here
const p1 = sum1(1)
.then(sum1)
.then(sum1)

Promise.all([p1])
.then(v => console.log(v[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about create a new function to do your task, it seems like promise.all does not fit to your case

```
const runInWaterfall = (promises) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const result = promises.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
        if(!acc) {
            return curr();
        }
        return acc.then(curr);
    }, null);
    result.then(resolve).catch(reject);
})
```

and your task can be rewritten as following

```
runInWaterfall([() => Promise.resolve(1), sum1, sum1, sum1]).then(result => console.log(result))
```